# Prestashop 1.7 product list, product view changes

Tags: smarty, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I'm trying to add some extra row after product image in prestashop 1.7 product list page.

I want to add manufacturer title above product title.

Already tried: 
Change product-list.tpl code.
.../themes/theme_name/templates/catalog/listing/
but nothing happened.

Here is product image with some info about my problem:

[image: Here is product image with some info about my problem]

Maybe some one know how to achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found something by my self. I'm not so sure why it happened but it was some of ".../app/cache/dev/..." - files.

Step by step:

```
 1. Download website file
 2. Search for specific classes
 3. Found those classes on two files product.tpl and f33as2f1a2sf5asfa2sfasf20132.file.product.tpl.php 
 4. Then back to my ftp found that second file with long name and change a code there...
 5. It works
```

Maybe its nasty work-around, so that's why I'm asking for more information for those who know more about things like this. Maybe there is something in back office (prestashop dashboard) settings... Developer/production mode or something? because by my opinion is just a nasty work around and I want to know more and learn more about it. Thanks.  <- **UPDATE:** -> its useless to edit cache files, you need to make changes ant clear cache from terminal || or admin dashboard.

**UPDATE BELOW  (in comments)--->>>**

Comment: Update: 

It was cache setting in prestashop dashboard. + Clean cache and turn on debug mode to see if something is wrong.

Comment: There are the cache files :) it's useless edit that files :).
To clear completely the cache you have to use a terminal command: `#php app/console cache:clear -e prod`

`#php app/console cache:clear -e dev`

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit this file:

`prestashop/themes/theme_name/templates/catalog/_partials/miniatures/product`

Under the block named `product_thumbnail` (also external to block if you want)

Comment: I tried this too, already, but nothing change. Maybe its not working because this is specific category product list? Is it posible? The file for this is category.tpl? I already try this too but it using product-list.tpl, which use product.tpl too. And I am little bit confused...

Comment: That is the file for the `classic` theme, I hope that a custom template have the same structure. Have you tried to clear cache? The new cache system is a little bit more annoying of the previous.